# Plotting Histogram with conditional bins range

Tags: python, pandas, histogram

I have written following code to plot histogram from given set of values in csv file column :

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot  as plt
import numpy

class createHistogram():

```
def __init__(self,csv_file):
    self.csv_file = csv_file

def load_csv(self):
    bin_edge = range(0,100,10)
    tp_data = pd.read_csv(self.csv_file)
    dataframe = pd.DataFrame(tp_data)['tp']
    dataframe.hist(bins=bin_edge)
    plt.show()
    return tp_data
```

Here I am getting histogram if values are less than 10, 20 ... and so on, but i want it should be

bin_value<=10

10< bin_value <=20

20

I am new to panda module..

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Pandas native `cut` which defines bins in the form of intervals.

```
ser = pd.Series(np.random.randint(1, 100, 50))
bins = range(0, 101, 10)
```

The `pd.cut` classifiies the data into bins using `Categorical` method.

```
In [4]: pd.cut(ser, bins).cat.categories
Out[4]: 
IntervalIndex([(0, 10], (10, 20], (20, 30], (30, 40], (40, 50], (50, 60], (60, 70], (70, 80], (80, 90], (90, 100]]
              closed='right',
              dtype='interval[int64]')
```

If you would like to further plot them, it would go something like this:

```
In [5]: pd.cut(ser, bins).value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
Out[5]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x10e673b70>
```

[image: Bar plot]

Comment: Thanks for the response ! Can you please tell me what is value_count() method? i am not able to get it

Comment: Value_counts generate a frequency table by generating 2 arrays, the unique entries, and their count.